# Why I can't run C++11?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, g++

I included chrono header and it wouldn't find it. I used the namespace chrono and it didn't compile it.

The question is, is this a problem of Eclipse or the compiler does not support C++11?
I have added in Eclipse the corresponding flag and macro.

Under this directory

> /usr/include/c++/4.3.2

I can not find chrono, only this file "c++0x_warning.h" regarding c++11.

The problem is that I am using a computer that I am not admin of and requesting a compiler's update would have me do a long procedure.

[This](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Pretty sure that means your compiler doesn't have the chrono library. There really is no solution other than upgrading.

Comment: BTW, I believe it's possible to install gcc in your home directory, but it's probably a bit tricky. (At the very least you need to tell the system to look for the C++ libraries there at runtime)

Comment: Is there any way to upgrade without being the admin?

Comment: [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/chrono.html) has an implementation of the Chrono library, if you can't update your compiler.

Comment: You can compile and build without admin rights a GCC 4.9.0 (or 4.8.2) with `../gcc-4.9.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/pub` then the binary goes into `$HOME/pub/bin/` which you could add to your `$PATH`

Comment: You cannot upgrade the system compiler without admin privileges obviously. But you can install your own version of any compiler in your home directory. A good opportunity to try clang? ;)

Comment: I am not interesting in chrono only. Moreover, even if I am obliged to use Boost (already have it), I do not want to use Boost more, it's not beautiful. What you say seems nice, but I am not sure about them, so better tell admin.

Comment: If you have not root privileges to install a new compiler, you maybe run in trouble while executing your compiled programs, because ldconfig/ldd has no knowledge how to find the libs. It is possible to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually, but this can also result in minor problems. Not a heavy problem, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a compiler with chrono support :-)

See:
http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html

gcc supports chrono from version 4.4. You compiler is simply much too old. Take the actual 4.9.0. So you have also regex as present :-)